# What is purpose of this diode?

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, schematics

Recently, I was exploring methods to distribute power akin to EURORACK systems, and I stumbled upon this schematic.

[image]

I've attempted to grasp the role of diode D4 in this setup, but regrettably, I've come up short. Could someone kindly elucidate the purpose of this diode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will protect the regulator from reverse bias breakdown.

As there are different manufacturers for 78XX type regulators, also the need and voltage limits for needing the diode varies.

If it happens that there is a lot of capacitance on regulator 5V output, and the input suddenly drops to 0V due to a short circuit or other scenario, there will be 5V voltage in reverse bias over the regulator and a lot of energy in capacitors on the 5V side.

To protect against input short circuit, there usually is a diode to keep the reverse bias below 1V, so when the input voltage drops, the diode pulls down the 5V output voltage by discharging the output capacitors so the current flows to input side.

Some datasheets say this is only needed if output voltage is greater than 6V or greater than approximately 7V, so depending on which exact regulator that is, the diode is not strictly needed to protect the regulator, however, it will still discharge the output capacitor rapidly. Some datasheets say the external diode is not needed if there is no more than 10uF of output capacitance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it provides a discharge path for the 5V circuit when the 12V supply is powered off, and prevents excessive reverse voltage across the regulator.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the combination of D4 and D5 may protect the downstream 5V circuits from destruction if the input polarity was reversed (assuming the input supply was current limited or protected with a fuse) or spikes from a highly inductive load.  A series diode would be the most obvious choice for reverse protection although it would potentially get quite hot at continuous full load.

From a 7805 protection viewpoint, I would not expect to see D4 used on its own unless there was significant capacitance on the 5V side, and a minimal load to discharge it. The diode is not going to conduct until the voltage across C4 is around 4.4V, and if the capacitors are leak free the only way they'll discharge (assuming no load) is through the regulator.

It does beg the question as to why one was not included in the regulator it if was essential?